# PPT changing color while converting with Unoconv

Tags: powerpoint, openoffice-impress, unoconv

I am converting PPT to PDF using Unoconv on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. Most of the files are being converted correctly, except few files. After conversion, the color of the slide becomes very bright. When I open the PPTx in "Microsoft Office PowerPoint" it appears correct, but when I open the same PPTx in "OpenOffice Impress" it appears same very bright color as it was after conversion. It may be CMYK to RGB issue but I am not sure.

Command I am using to convert PPT to PDF is:

```
/usr/bin/unoconv -f pdf PPT_File_Name
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Source file:
[PPTx source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19ioLkS7iyATmh0NTlqbWJVblE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your guess is correct:  the images in PPT are CMYK JPGs.  If you rename the PPTX to give it a .ZIP extension, you can open it up, browse to the ppt/media folder and you'll find the two images there to examine if you like.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, Is there any solution for it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to replace the CMYK JPGs with RGB ones.